# Magento2.3.5 configurable products not showing out of stock product

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, out-of-stock

I am having issue with showing out of stock products. When all child products of configurable product are out of stock then it donot show out of stock products. If any of them is in stock then it shows all childs (instock & outofstock).

Answer (score 0):

please install below module. it will fix your problem

https://github.com/interjar/configurable-child-visibility

accept answer if works for you

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/189445)

Comment: Its a large module with many files. Otherwise I prefer to post here instead of link. I hope you understand.